# Побитовые операции в Java

Tags: java, битовые-операции

```
class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        char ch;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            ch = (char) ('A' + i);
            System.out.print(ch);

            ch = (char)((int)ch | 32);

            System.out.print(ch + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Почему в данном случае он мне переводит большие буквы в маленькие меняя шестой бит, а если я поменяю на &(и) он мне не меняет маленькие на большие. И такое только с числом в десятичной системе, если я переведу его в двоичную или восьмеричную, то все норм. ?

Comment: а вопрос то в чём? Как все буквы на большие поменять? например `(int)ch & (-1 ^ 32)`

Comment: вопрос в том что в побитовом (или) я могу использовать 32(десят.число), а в побитовом (и) не могу.

Comment: можешь... почему нет?

Comment: вопрос закрыт, до меня дошло :) спасибо.